# bootstrap 4 with codeignitor form with validation

Tags: php, html, bootstrap-4, codeigniter-3, responsive

**Not showing *responsive* in safari browser Responsive issue**
*I am unable to control to responsive this code, working fine in windows chrome and Mozilla, but not on mac. can anyone help me?*

```
<?php echo form_open('user/signup');?>
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
          <div class="form-label-group">
            <?php echo form_input(['name'=>'firstname','id'=>'firstname','class'=>'form-control','autofocus'=>'autofocus','value'=>set_value('firstname')]);?>
            <?php echo form_label('Enter your first name', 'firstname'); ?>
            <?php echo form_error('firstname',"<div style='color:red'>","</div>");?>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
          <div class="form-label-group">
            <?php echo form_input(['name'=>'lastname','id'=>'lastname','class'=>'form-control','autofocus'=>'autofocus','value'=>set_value('lastname')]);?>
            <?php echo form_label('Enter your  last name', 'lastname'); ?>
            <?php echo form_error('lastname',"<div style='color:red'>","</div>");?>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="form-label-group">
        <?php echo form_input(['name'=>'emailid','id'=>'emailid','class'=>'form-control','autofocus'=>'autofocus','value'=>set_value('emailid')]);?>
        <?php echo form_label('Enter valid email id', 'emailid'); ?>
        <?php echo form_error('emailid',"<div style='color:red'>","</div>");?>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="form-label-group">
        <?php echo form_input(['name'=>'mobilenumber','id'=>'mobilenumber','class'=>'form-control','autofocus'=>'autofocus','value'=>set_value('mobilenumber')]);?>
        <?php echo form_label('Enter Mobile Number', 'mobilenumber'); ?>
        <?php echo form_error('mobilenumber',"<div style='color:red'>","</div>");?>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="form-label-group">
            <?php echo form_password(['name'=>'password','id'=>'password','class'=>'form-control','autofocus'=>'autofocus','value'=>set_value('password')]);?>
            <?php echo form_label('Password', 'password'); ?>
            <?php echo form_error('password',"<div style='color:red'>","</div>");?>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="form-label-group">
            <?php echo form_password(['name'=>'confirmpassword','id'=>'confirmpassword','class'=>'form-control','autofocus'=>'autofocus','value'=>set_value('confirmpassword')]);?>
            <?php echo form_label('Confirm Password', 'confirmpassword'); ?>
            <?php echo form_error('confirmpassword',"<div style='color:red'>","</div>");?>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <?php echo form_submit(['name'=>'Register','value'=>'Register','class'=>'btn btn-primary btn-block']); ?>
    <?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

> How do I solve this issue
>   **Responsive issue on safari**
>   **100% working in windows chrome**

Comment: View Source link - view-source:techwob.com/dbtsoft/user/Signup

Comment: What's the exact problem here? How is a responsive layout related to PHP or any PHP framework?

Comment: @NicoHaase Kindly run this link in safari browser you can will see the issue:-techwob.com/dbtsoft/user/Signup

Comment: Please edit your question to contain all such information. And no, I don't want to visit any site and guess what is wrong